# how to define functions in C header files

Tags: c, header-files

I found this on a header file, and I am not sure what this does. 
why is there a `define` followed by 2 functions?

```
#ifndef BCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY
#define delay(x) bcm2835_delay(x)
#define delayMicroseconds(x) bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(x)
#endif
```

and later on the file I see both functions again as:

```
extern void bcm2835_delay (unsigned int millis);
extern void bcm2835_delayMicroseconds (uint64_t micros);
```

Comment: You should start with a C book learning the basics.

Comment: Do you know what preprocessor macros are?

Comment: Those are not functions, they are macros. They will basically replace a piece of code for another just before compilation, in a step known as preprocessor.

Comment: i believe so, correct me if im wrong, anytime the delay function is called bcm2835 will be called?

Comment: Every time you call `delay(something)` it will be replaced by `bcm2835_delay(something)` just before compilation. `delay` is not a function and doesn't exist at any shape in time as far as the compiler and final binary knows, its basically a text replacement in the code.

Comment: "anytime the delay function is called bcm2835 will be called?" That is correct, provided that the macros indeed got defined which depends on whether BCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY was defined or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements after the `#define` are in fact not functions, but pre-processor macros.

The purpose of a macro is to substitute text within the source code before the compilation process. Meaning, everywhere the programmer types `delay(x)` in a file which includes this header, it will be replaced with `bcm2835_delay(x)`. Similarly with `delayMicroseconds(x)` and `bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(x)` (Only if `BCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY` has not beed defined, of course).

The later declarations which you speak of, are actual function declarations-- in fact for the functions which the macros are calling.

On a somewhat un-related note, it is important you distinguish a function being defined, from a function being declared (neither of which have to do with `#define`, as that defines a macro-- not a function!)

The functions in the .h file are declared. In fact, the `extern` keyword specifies they will be defined outside of the scope of this file.

A function definition on the other hand, would contain braces `{...}` with the behavior defined inside.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is first checking to see if there is a value defined.  It appears that this value `BCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY` toggles on and off compatibility with a particular set of timers.  If it isn't defined (in other words, if it's not turned off) then the two *macros* are defined to point to an actual function.

Later, those actual functions are defined.

Was there some other question??

Comment: I suppose OP is lacking the very basic stuff of C language. This question will very likely have to end up as a tutorial.

Comment: @olaf Agreed.  I disagree with the closure.  This isn't broad at all.  Very specific though very basic.

Comment: thanks David, i think i get it, i just need to see where the value `BCM2835_NO_DELAY_COMPATIBILITY` is declared., and @Olaf you dont need to be that harsh, just trying to learn.

Comment: It's not declared... If it is, those macros won't execute.  (or it might be and the macros become moot)

Comment: @pato.llaguno: Where was I harsh? I just stated the obvious. No need to feel offended by clear language. Point is this is no tutorial site, nor forum, but Q&A and you should first read a good C book or get a - well - tutorial. - Really no offense!

Comment: @Olaf Suggestion: Comments that focus on the post and not the person as in "OP is lacking the very basic stuff of C" are [nicer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @chux: Acknowledged - I could have said that a bit nicer and added the typical "no offense" disclaimer. But for the contents, I stick to the old idea of "give a man a fish and you feed him one day. Teach him how to fish, and you feed him for his life."